# React change css of class when element is not in website from beginning

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to change CSS of element `<div class="myClass1">"I am content"</div>` in react. Basically, I just want to add `"display: none;"` Problem is that that element is created by one library on click so I cant really set style or class to state or variable or something. In jQuery there is a lot of ways but how to do this in react?

Here is my handler

```
  // Handling change
  const handleChange = () => {
   // Here should be code to change css of myClass1
  };
```

Comment: You need to provide a working example on codesandbox, so we can help.

Comment: If you already know the class name then put CSS style in your stylesheet, it will automatically work. If you want to override then use `!important`

Comment: Have you tried having a state variable in your component, and then doing some sort of a conditional rendering? React will re-render a particular block when it detects a state change.

Comment: Also, you can do DOM manipulation in React as well, if you don't want to remove the complete component and only some element out of it.

Comment: I overcome it with some css somehow. But i am deffinitely going to check that DOM manipulation i will need it later. Thank guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional class name for that. In your `handleChange` set a boolean state and in your className use this state to change className. Then in this new className you can apply `display: none` .

```
<div class={`${clicked ? "myClass1" : "myClass2"}`}>"I am content"</div>
```

In this case clicked would be your state that you can change with `handleChange` function

Comment: Thats the problem i cant edit something inside div because its generated from library.

Comment: DOM manipulation then. Just remove the className and add new one. Or just add new one with a space in the beginning something like "  newClassName"